# Как заменить в тексте все квадратные скобки на  скобки?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Как заменить в тексте все квадратные скобки на `<>` скобки?
Есть, допустим, `[table][tr][tr][menu][/td][/tr][/table]`.
Как мне заменить все `[` на `<`, a `]` на `>`?
Какая регулярка должка быть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не пойму, зачем тут RegExp, т.к. такая задача - точно решается простой заменой.
JavaScript:

```
str = '[table][tr][tr][menu][/td][/tr][/table]';
str.replace(/\[|\]/gm, function(el){
    if ( el == ']' ) return '>';
    return '<';
});
```

Можно ещё так ( php ):

```
str_replace( array('[',']'), array('<','>'), $str);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var str = "[b][script]document.write(document.cookie);[/script][/b]";
var s = str.replace(/\[/g, '<').replace(/\]/g, '>');
```

php:

```
$str = "[b][script]document.write(document.cookie);[/script][/b]";
$s = strtr($str, '[]', '<>');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?
$str = str_replace('[','<',$str);
$str = str_replace(']','>',$str);
?>
```

Тоже только на php

Comment: Для php вопрос и был.